# Volume of a particular snowcone.

Tags: integration

This 'snowcone' is different in that the cone is the paraboloid az=x^2+y^2and the top is the sphere x^2+y^2+z^2=2a^2. The circle of intersection  becomes (x^2+y^2)/a = sqrt (2a^2-x^2-y^2). I can't proceed further to get the equation of the projected circle in the xy-plane. Any ideas?

Comment: Substitute the first equation into the second and solve for $z$.

Comment: I did the substitution and got z=a/2 (sqrt7-1). This does not give me the equation of intersection of the two solids. I need this to get the limits for dr and d (theta).

Comment: Of course it doesn’t. That gives you the value(s) of $z$ at which the two surfaces intersect, from which computing the circle’s radius should be straightforward. BTW, your value for $z$ is way off.

Comment: I redid the calculation and got z=a, which is also the radius of projected circle. I hope this is corrected.

Comment: Now you’ve got it.